# on macOS compile for armv7l running linux

Tags: linux, macos, cross-compiling, armv7

I want to build https://github.com/relan/exfat for my router on my macbook

```
# uname -a
Linux RT-N18U 2.6.36.4brcmarm #1 PREEMPT Fri Jan 12 18:35:32 CST 2018 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

I found following solutions with the corresponding hurdles

1. https://github.com/tpoechtrager/osxcross - how to set the target?
2. https://github.com/multiarch/crossbuild - how to build an `autoconf` project?

During 2nd solution, I get the following error

```
$ docker run --rm -v ~/workspace/exfat/:/workdir -e CROSS_TRIPLE=armv7l multiarch/crossbuild autoreconf --install
configure.ac:32: installing './ar-lib'
configure.ac:29: installing './compile'
configure.ac:28: installing './install-sh'
configure.ac:28: installing './missing'
dump/Makefile.am: installing './depcomp'
$ docker run --rm -v ~/workspace/exfat/:/workdir -e CROSS_TRIPLE=armv7l multiarch/crossbuild ./configure
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
...
...
checking for special C compiler options needed for large files... no
checking for _FILE_OFFSET_BITS value needed for large files... 64
./configure: line 4080: syntax error near unexpected token `FUSE,'
./configure: line 4080: `PKG_CHECK_MODULES(FUSE, fuse)'
```

Comment: What isn't working? Please clarify the exact problem

Comment: the docker image doesn't have `fuse` module